# duplicated DIV's buttons not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am implementing a tic tac toe game but with special specification that when I press a button it open a new DIV of the game and disable the old one and the button pressed must be changed in both DIV and so on but I have a small problem here.
Why the buttons in the other div function doesn't work like the first one?

```js
var c = new Number(); 
c=0;
i=0;

var name = "xo"+c;
    
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        alert("hi");
      newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        newDiv.className="xo";
      var $copy =$("#xo0").html()
      document.getElementById(name).appendChild(newDiv);
        var allChildNodes = document.getElementById(name).getElementsByTagName('*');
        for(var i = 0; i < allChildNodes.length; i++)
        {
            allChildNodes[i].disabled = true;
        } 
      c++;
      name = "xo"+c;
      newDiv.id=name; 
      alert(name);
      
      $("#"+name).html($copy);
      $("#"+name).insertAfter($("#xo0"));
    });
});
```

```css
.xo {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #F03;
    height: 300px;
    width: 310px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    float: left;
}
.btn {
    background-color: #0C9;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<div align="left" class="xo" id="xo0">
    <input type="submit" class="btn" name="1" id="1" value="Submit" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn" name="2" id="2" value="Submit" />
    <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn" id="3" value="Submit" />
        
    <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn" id="4" value="Submit" />
    <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn" id="5" value="Submit" />
    <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn" id="6" value="Submit" />
         
    <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn" id="7" value="Submit" />
    <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn" id="8" value="Submit" />
    <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn" id="9" value="Submit" />
        
    <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function only binds event handler to matching elements that are currently present. For attaching handler to dynamically added elements you can make use of event delegation using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method as follows:

`$(document).on('click','.btn',function(){...})`

Comment: Thanks for the great answer but now i have problem when i click in the new div a button the original div get the change and not the one im trying to change

Comment: @AhmedShaaban not sure what you meant by "change", does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/9sW7u/) fix the issue..? would be better if you explain what you're trying to do in another Q because looks like this can be done with way less code if you go with pure jquery… :)

Comment: great :) just a side note - instead of `document.getElementById(name).getElementsByTagName('*');` you can do `document.getElementById(name).childNodes;` in js, even better `$('#'+name).children()` with query..